# Send attached file with mailx

Tags: unix

I am trying to send attached file with uuencode from shell script this way:

```
uuencode logq.txt logq.txt |mail -s "DB Capacity" xxxx@000.net
```

I recieve the file encrypted and not even attached..

e.g -

```
begin 664 logq.txt
M"E1U92!-87(@,CD@(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @ M(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @<&%G92 @(" Q"B @(" @(" @ M(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @(" @4$U-($1"($-!4$%
```

Can some one give me an idea how to solved it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send a file as an email attachment using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer to this question: [How to send HTML body email with multiple text attachments using sendmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395082/how-to-send-multiple-attachments-using-sendmail/5395442#5395442) on how to send attachments in Unix bash scripts.

## EDIT

Based on your latest requirements here is a simple Unix script to send plain text attachment:

```
FROM=from-email@example.com
TO=to-email@example.com
SUBJECT="PMM DB CAPACITY"
BODY="Hi, This email comes with a text attachment. Thanks!"
TXTFILE="/tti/netrac/integration/scripts/maint_scripts/log.txt log.txt"    
BOUNDARY="=== This is the boundary between parts of the message. ==="
{
   echo  "From: ${FROM}"
   echo  "To: ${TO}"
   echo  "Subject: ${SUBJECT}"
   echo  "MIME-Version: 1.0"
   echo  "Content-Type: MULTIPART/MIXED; "
   echo  "    BOUNDARY="\"${BOUNDARY}\"
   echo
   echo  "        This message is in MIME format.  But if you can see this,"
   echo  "        you aren't using a MIME aware mail program.  You shouldn't "
   echo  "        have too many problems because this message is entirely in"
   echo  "        ASCII and is designed to be readable with old mail software."
   echo
   echo  "--${BOUNDARY}"
   echo  "Content-Type: TEXT/PLAIN; charset=US-ASCII"
   echo
   echo  "${BODY}"
   echo
   echo
   echo  "--${BOUNDARY}"
   echo  "Content-Type: TEXT/PLAIN; charset=US-ASCII; name="${TXTFILE}
   echo  "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="`$(basename ${TXTFILE})
   echo
   cat ${TXTFILE}
   echo
   echo  "--${BOUNDARY}--"
} | sendmail -t
```

Just make sure you have sendmail in your bash path.

## Alternative command to send attachment

```
(echo "Hi, this mail has an attachment."; uuencode attachment.txt attachment.txt) | mail -s "Some Subject" to-email@example.com
```

Comment: where i add the file? to $ZIP? is it var that hold the var?

Comment: Yes that example is attaching 2 files. 1: Shell var $ZIPFILE should point to a zip with the content-type `application/zip` and 2: $PDFFILE should point to a pdf with the content-type `application/pdf` So depending upon your needs please feel free to change the variable names and their content types.

Comment: hi, at first i will acknowledge my gratitude to you.

Comment: .... second - my problem is that i recieve the txt file encoded without an option to decode it in my outlook. thanks

Comment: @user644535: I also use Outlook and able to receive all those attachments fine in Outlook. May I know what type of attachment you are trying to send eg: text, csv, doc, pdf etc then I can customize that code for your needs and update my answer.

Comment: i will attachted my code and you may review your answer relate to what i did so far. 
FROM=new-pmm@xxxx.net
TO=abc@xxxx.net
SUBJECT="PMM DB CAPACITY"
TXT= /tti/netrac/integration/scripts/maint_scripts/log.txt
{ echo  "From: $FROM"
echo  "To: $TO"
echo  "Subject:" $SUBJECT
echo  "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo  "--${BOUNDARY}"
echo  "Content-Type:TXT/PLAIN; charset=US-ASCII name=eeee" echo  "Content-Disposition: attachment;   filename=log"
uuencode /tti/netrac/integration/scripts/maint_scripts/log.txt log.txt
}|/usr/lib/sendmail -t

Comment: @user644535: I have provided the modified script in my answer above. Since you need to send only text attachment therefore there is no need to use uuencode here, I have tested it and I am able to open the attachment fine in my Outlook as well :)

Comment: ... i done it but i didnt recieve any mail or error that correspond it, may be it relate to your comment -  "Just make sure you have sendmail in your bash path.
"? i gave the path as /usr/lib/sendmail -t. or rather i check some firewall definition?

Comment: @user644535: Yes please check whether you have an executable `sendmail in /usr/lib/sendmail` if not you can try alternative `uuencode/mail` command above in my answer.