# unix, email attachment not being attached

Tags: bash, unix, uuencode

I am trying to send an attachment via a script and the logic works if i run manually but not as part of the script.  if I add echo, the email goes out and populates with uuencode jef20.txt jef20.txt but no attachment.  any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Your Username?
read user
echo FIX Session?
read session
echo what client?
read client
awk '!/35=0|35=A|35=5|35=2|35=1|closed/'  /company/gate/app_phoenix/logs/fix/$session >> /home/dnash/$client.txt
uuencode $client.txt $client.txt | mailx -s "Cert Logs" "$user@company.com"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is always recommended to wrap your samples in CODE TAGS a `{}` button you will see while posting on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of `mailx` , you can use the `-a` ( "attach" ) command line switch:

```
mailx -a "$client.txt" -s "Cert Logs" "$user@company.com"
```

#### See Also

[mailx manpage](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-mailx/)

[how to send an email via mailx with enclosed file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408243/how-to-send-an-email-via-mailx-with-enclosed-file)